# Get the number of lanes for the given edge ID in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I would like to get the number of the lanes for a particle edge in Veins.

I implemented the getLaneNumber(EdgeId) TraCI command as illustrated in [Edge Value Retrieval](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Edge_Value_Retrieval). My implementation is:

```
int32_t TraCICommandInterface::Road::getLaneNumber(){
return traci->genericGetInt(CMD_GET_EDGE_VARIABLE, roadId, VAR_LANE_INDEX, 
RESPONSE_GET_EDGE_VARIABLE);
}
```

But, I got the following error:

> TraCI server reported error executing command 0xaa ("Get Edge
>   Variable: unsupported variable 0x52 specified").

Any idea why 0x52 is not supported for get edge variable although command 0x52 is listed in TraCI wiki?

Comment: Which version of SUMO are you using?

Comment: I use veins-4.7.1 with sumo-0.32.0

Answer (score 1):

The wiki reflects the current state of the GitHub master not the latest release. The function you are trying to use has been added shortly after the last release 0.32.0 (and yes it is time for a new release). Please try again with a nightly build.